# preg_match to get mp3 and mp4 filenames in file extension order then in filename order from an external webpage?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. I have tried many times and cannot come up with the search pattern to get all the mp3 and mp4 files name from an external HTML.  The list of files is in file extension order than the file name order.  I would appreciate if any help.

```
$file = 'http://70.123.0.111//lrs/35/';
$searchfor = '<a herf';
echo $searchfor;

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');

// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/";

// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
```

### HTML codes

70.123.0.111 - /lrs/35/

## 70.123.0.111 - /lrs/35/

---

```
[To Parent Directory]

 7/17/2008  9:02 PM    178899264 0102.mp3
 7/18/2008 12:30 AM    558244970 0102.mp4
 7/17/2008  9:38 PM    186016896 0304.mp3
 7/18/2008  1:44 AM    580476123 0304.mp4
 7/17/2008 10:13 PM    186478272 0506.mp3
 7/18/2008  2:59 AM    581455848 0506.mp4
 7/17/2008 10:44 PM    166862592 0708.mp3
 7/18/2008  4:02 AM    520139478 0708.mp4
 7/17/2008 11:19 PM    188616096 0910.mp3
 7/18/2008  5:16 AM    590308801 0910.mp4
12/11/2008  8:15 PM       688347 qfm_hetu_vidya.pdf
12/11/2008  2:08 PM       421978 ym_notes.pdf
```

---

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you provided?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are new to regex then [www.rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com) should be your new friend.

Assumming the text document will always be as you have it, and you don't have any spaces in file names, then this regex will do: "/(\w+.mp[34])/"

This code below works for me (not sure what $searchfor variable is for). Hope this helps.

```
$file = 'test.html';
//$searchfor = '<a herf';
//echo $searchfor;

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/(\w+\.mp[34])/";

// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your problem is in the second line of your code:
$searchfor = 'herf';

(use href instead of herf)